# How to make a screen reader option

Tags: android, html, pdf, mobile, accessibility

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ9Bi.png

On this page there is a green icon next to the RSS button for screen readers.

How do I get this on my own website?

Comment: I don't have an exact answer, but I think it has to deal with semantic markup in the webpage, such as sections and headlines etc. See http://www.readability.com/developers/guidelines

Comment: So it only applies to articles?

Comment: Not necesarily on the content, but how it's marked up. It's a matter of giving hints as to what is important and what can be left out.

Comment: I think this question is incorrect. That looks like a 'read later' icon. Screen readers will read the contents of a page automatically, there's no need to activate them on a page level.

Comment: RSS has nothing to do with Assistive Technology (ie: screen readers.)

Comment: Hmm, how do I allow for a read later icon? When you click on it the browser takes you to a "Reader" page.

Comment: Also I'm not saying that RSS is for screen readers... I thought that the green button was.

Comment: You get that icon by installing the app / pluggin, or perhaps it is built into your phone? It is not something you add to a site, and it's nothing to do with screen readers.

Comment: @Neel: What happens when you activate this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there is no way to force a Reader button. The button naturally shows up on some pages, sometimes not.